# numpy recfromcsv and genfromtxt skips first row of data file

Tags: python, numpy, io, scipy

numpy's recfromcsv skips the first line of my data.  (Same thing for genfromtxt)

```
import numpy as np

filename = 'data.csv'
writer = open(filename,mode='w')
writer.write('0,1.1,1.2\n1,2.1,2.2\n2,3.1,3.2')
writer.close()

data = np.recfromcsv(filename)
print data
```

Is this a bug, or how can I load the data without loosing the first line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default first line of a csv file contains the field names.
The function `recfromcsv` invoke `genfromtxt` with parameters `names=True` as default. It means that it read the first line of the data as the header.

Definition: 
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

You should write it before the array.

```
import numpy as np

filename = 'data.csv'
writer = open(filename,mode='w')
writer.write('first column,second column,third column\n')
writer.write('0,1.1,1.2\n1,2.1,2.2\n2,3.1,3.2')
writer.close()

data = np.recfromcsv(filename)
print data
```

Or use `recfromtxt` instead of `recfromcsv`.

Or overwrite the default name as

```
recfromcsv(filename, names=['a','a','a'])
```

Comment: In my case the data file format is fixed -- but giving names does the trick.  (...note that you've got an extra set of quotes in your code: should be recfromcsv(filename, names=['a','a','a'])

Answer (score 5):

You can add `skiprow=0` to keep recfromcsv from skipping the first row.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of `recfromcsv` is to read a header row, which is why it's skipping the first row.  It works for me with `genfromtxt` (if I pass `delimiter=','`).  Can you provide output showing how `genfromtxt` fails?

Unfortunately it seems there is a bug in Numpy that won't let you specify the dtype in `recfromcsv` (see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/311), so I can't see how to read it in with specified column names, which I think is what you need to do to avoid reading the header line.  But you can read the data in with `genfromtxt`.

Edit: It looks like you can read it in just by passing in a list of names:

```
np.recfromcsv(filename, delimiter=',', names=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

(The reason it wasn't working for me is I had done `from __future__ import unicode_literals` and it apparently doesn't like unicode in dtypes.)

Comment: Anf if you want to keep the result as a structured array with int for the first volumn and float for the other columns as you would get from ``recfromcsv``, you also can specify the keyword ``dtype=None``